# Cakephp Home Page logic

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I suddenly wonder.. for the home page which points to controller => pages
action => display and home... where do i write the controller logic ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the PagesController (which you can copy from `cake/libs/controller`). Or you can change the route for "/" to point to a controller/action of your choice.

Comment: can i place a pages controller in app/controller ? can pages controller have actions ?

Comment: @Harsha The pages controller is nothing special. Just look at it in `cake/libs/controller/pages_controller.php`. Place your own `pages_controller.php` in `app/controllers` to override it with your own version, which can do anything a normal controller can.

Comment: awesome :D   but i have a few pages in the views/pages folder. so i will have to shift it to views/pages right ?

Comment: @Harsha, I believe they are in views/pages already :) You should just rewrite the display action, or just to create a new one (i.e. called home() for the homepage) and put your desired logic there. Then just change the route / to point to /pages/home and you are done

Answer (score 3):

@dhofstet: Thank you!

Now I can access my homepage

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'));
```

without being logged in.

This is my **app/controllers/pages_controller.php**:

```
<?php
class PagesController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Pages';
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Session');
    var $uses = array();

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('home');
    }

    function home() {
    }

    function display() {
        $path = func_get_args();

        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));
    }
}
?>
```